# how to play .flv files in the media element provided in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, media, element

I would like to build a component to play all the audio/media files(especially .flv files) using asp.net.so could you please provide me the necessary code/idea to create the component

Comment: what u ended up doing ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ASP.NET Component for playing media, then you should be looking at Silverlight instead of WPF, but Silverlight (probably) won't play FLV files.

Comment: I asked the same question 1 hour ago .. Silverlight media player wont play these extensions : api ,flv,mp4,swf .. neither the media element

Comment: @Grace - SWF isn't necessarily a video, you would need the Flash player to execute it. FLV & MP4 can be played with a simple Flash video player eg FlowPlayer

Comment: yes and FlowPlayer will only okay flv & mp4. isnt there a media player who can play all of them at the same time ????

Comment: @Grace I've seen solutions which use type detection to determine which player to load up - but they're still loading silverlight, flash, or other components to do this. Flash doesn't handle encrypted Windows video/audio content, and vice versa.